# dmesg shows 8GB memory as 6059MB real

Tags: memory, ram

free -h and dmesg commands show real memory as about 6GB while I installed an 8GB ram. The following is the output of the commands

```
dmesg | grep -i mem
```

real mem = 6353747968 (6059MB) avail mem = 6146134016 (5861MB) spdmem0 at iic0 addr 0x50: 8GB DDR4 SDRAM PC4-17000

```
grep -i mem /var/run/dmesg.boot
```

real mem = 6353747968 (6059MB) avail mem = 6146134016 (5861MB) spdmem0 at iic0 addr 0x50: 8GB DDR4 SDRAM PC4-17000

Results did not vary between Ubuntu 20.04 and OpenBSD. Am I missing something here please?

Comment: This doesn't happen to be an HP machine is it.  Please list your system spec.

Comment: is the full amount of RAM detected in BIOS? if so, are integrated graphics enabled? (that steals a buffer's worth)

Comment: Please tell us what is your PC.

Comment: Jason Croyle It is amd64 with ASUS Prime A 320 M-K motherboard, Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphicsbash-5.0$ sysctl grep hw
sysctl: top level name grep in grep is invalid
hw.machine=amd64
hw.model=AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics
hw.ncpu=4
hw.byteorder=1234
hw.pagesize=4096
hw.sensors.ksmn0.temp0=46.50 degC
hw.cpuspeed=3593
hw.setperf=100
hw.vendor=ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
hw.product=PRIME A320M-K
hw.physmem=6353747968
hw.usermem=6353715200
hw.ncpufound=4
hw.allowpowerdown=1
hw.smt=0
hw.ncpuonline=4

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things that can cause this but by far the most common is integrated graphics then the system assigns a block of your ram to the gpu/apu.

Comment: @Fox Yes, bios shows Memory as 8192 MB Ram. You are right. Though I don't see any settings enabaling or disabling integrated graphics, the processor happens to be an AMD Rhyzon 3200 with integrated radeon graphics,

Comment: If you see no setting in the bios to disable it you can check with the motherboard manufacture to see if there is any bios updates if this is a laptop then you can check with them also.  IMPORTANT if there is an update available make sure you verify every detail to make sure it is for your model and verify the installation procedure you can brick a motherboard if done incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you Jason. (It is Ryzen, sorry) If indeed the 2GB is assigned to graphics, it is fine, but I don't see any explicit indiction in bios nor from the command line. It is quite possible that this has something to do with the bios, may not be anything wrong with the functionality, I haven't gone deeper into bios settings.  @psusi

Comment: It’s probably worth checking into the bios update but beyond that your probably running out of options.  This situation does have an upside if you ever want to do gpu pass through for a virtual machine you can use the integrated graphics for the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `dmesg` for the e820 bios memory map.  It will show what chunks of ram the bios has marked reserved for various things, which may include integrated graphics chip memory.  This memory is subtracted from the amount available to the kernel.  Often motherboards reserve everything between 3 and 4 GB for video cards and other devices, and some older ones do not have the ability to relocate the RAM there to higher addresses, rendering it unusable.  Or some motherboards may have the ability, but their BIOS fails to use it.  Since you are missing ~2GB of RAM, most likely you just have a really bad BIOS and should check with your motherboard manufacturer for an update.

Comment: dmesg doesn't show anything so detailed except show real memory and available memory both around 6GB.  Is there a specific dmesg command for this please?

Comment: @amsyvah, look for "e820".  Or I can't remember if you boot in EFI mode then it says something about EFI instead of e820?  It's a table with a bunch of ranges in hexadecimal with words at the end like "usable" or "reserved".  It should be one of the very first things the kernel prints.

Comment: @psui Is there a way to capture all the text that scroll past during boot, please?

Comment: @amsyvah, check your syslogs: either look in /var/log/kern.log or run `journalctl -k`

Comment: Both are long files:                                                                        
Mar  8 15:09:37 : [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Mar  8 15:09:37  BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f33ffff] usable
Mar  8 15::   NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Mar  8 15::  SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.
Mar  8 15:: DMI: PRIME A320M-K, BIOS 5602 07/14/2020
Mar  8 15:: tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
Mar  8 15:09: e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
Mar  8 15:09: e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable

Comment: @amsyvah, is that the full map?  I only see one chunk of usable ram and it is only 4.8 GB long starting at the 4 GB mark.  There's no entry describing any memory below 4 GB as usable.

Answer (score 0):

@psui Posting as a reply because the comment field does not allow a link to be shown as a link:

```
/var/log/kern.log
```

is [here](https://gofile.io/d/9GSlse)  and `journalctl -k` is [here](https://gofile.io/d/lgy7U2)

Thank you.